# getElementByID won't pass the values to variables

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript

```
function fn1(){
    var a = document.getElementById("xa").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("ya").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("xb").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("yb").value;

    fn2(a,b,c,d);
}
```

HTML

```
<div align="center"><b>Digital Differential Analyzer</b><br /><br />
    X0: <input type="text" id="xa"/>
    Y0: <input type="text" id="ya"/>
    XE: <input type="text" id="xb"/>
    YE: <input type="text" id="yb"/>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="e.width = e.width;fn1();" /></div>
```

If I enter function1 as only the call to function2 with ready values (such as 0,0,300,300), it works fine, but when I try to get the variables with getElementById, nothing works, I tried to modify it a lot but still the same result, and it doesn't even show as an error

Comment: where is fn2() definition? `document.getElementById("xa").value` returns a string value, is your fn2 ready to accept strings?

Comment: thank you, used parseInt and it solved it, for some reason I thought value would return an Int despite the fact it's a textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
 fn2(+a,+b,+c,+d);
```

this will convert input values from string to int. your function is not working because you are passing string values to the funcrion.
it adds 0 to the variable a,b,c,d respectively and casts string to int
i.e. 0+a=a but now 'a' is int. 
for more accuracy try with `parseFloat()`

```
function fn1(){
 var a =parseFloat( document.getElementById("xa").value);
 var b =parseFloat( document.getElementById("ya").value);
 var c =parseFloat( document.getElementById("xb").value);
 var d =parseFloat( document.getElementById("yb").value);

  fn2(a,b,c,d); 

}
```